# Why does subprocess.Popen run in parallel but subprocess.run does not

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, subprocess

I would like to perform an expensive IO operation in parallel in a subprocess. However, when I execute the following code, it runs sequentially and takes forever to complete:

```py
import subprocess
import csv

processes = []

with open(f'identifiers.csv', 'r', newline='') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        id = row['id']
        p = subprocess.run(f'expensive_io_operation {id}', shell=True)
        processes.append(p)
for process in processes:
    process.wait()
```

This block of code runs sequentially.

However, if I replace `subprocess.run` with `subprocess.Popen`, then this block of code will execute in parallel.

I would like to understand why.

Comment: This is why [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) exists … documentation which clearly states “…. Wait for command to complete”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly documented; `subprocess.run` blocks and waits for the subprocess to finish. If you want to run a parallel subprocess, you need `Popen`; but then you also need to do the required management of the subprocess object which `run` takes care of for you behind the scenes. (And indeed, the `CompletedProcess` object returned by `run` obviously doesn't have a  `wait` method, because, uh, it's completed.)

Tangentially, if speed is important, you really want to avoid the completely superflous [`shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess); on Unix-like systems, you then need to break up the command to a list of strings (or use `shlex.split()`).

```
        p = child_processes.Popen(['expensive_io_operation', id])
```

In this context, gluing the parts into a single string so that a shell is needed to take them apart again is obviously also unnecessary and slightly  wasteful.

If the expensive operation is I/O bound, you have to be careful about where you add parallell processing. Throwing more CPU at a problem which is already saturating your I/O bandwidth will only add congestion, and make things slower.

Perhaps also look at `multiprocessing` which can take care of running a *controlled* number of parallel tasks and collect their results. With `multiprocessing.Pool` and a queue, you can run, say, 16 processes in parallel and divide the tasks from the queue between them according to their availability, and without the nitty-gritty of managing the individual processes yourself.

Finally, for I/O where many tasks involve a lot of waiting, perhaps instead look into `async`, which lets you implement (apparent) parallellism in a single process by way of dividing the work into non-blocking fragments where Python takes care of switching between them whenever they reach an `await` statement (or etc; this brief exposition is obviously abridged).